# Exporting label rendering options based on zoom level correctly in QGIS

Tags: qgis, leaflet, openlayers, qgis2web

I am making a webmap using QGIS3.
However, I set the text-label to be invisible from a certain zoom-level onward, and visible from another zoom-level. It displays correctly locally in QGIS edit screen but it does not work after I export it to web. (using qgis2web plugin)

**Goal: to make text disappear at 1:1800 scale(zoom) level and above. (text appear below 1:1800 when zooming out)**

This is what I mean:
[image: setting panel for label display]

Result after exporting is that "Lot number and land area" will not even show up at all.
I try both OpenLayers and Leaflet.

(this is the example with no label display setting based on zoom level)
--> export outcome: https://landing-at-ven.web.app/kelson_output_1/index.html
--> Ideally, I want to ***hide the appearance of text label totally*** when I zoom out to a certain level.

Bad impression:
[image]

I wonder is there anyway I can modify the output code to modify and realize what I want to achieve or am I getting some settings wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `qgis2web` plugin and the maps it creates, but if it creates vector layers, you'll have to modify the created Leaflet/OpenLayers code and do the zoom filtering on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is not possible. Working with labels is difficult within qgis2web.
You have two possibilities:

1. `Vector - Geometry tools - Centroids`
   Save your layer. Set zoom/scale level for the layer, NOT for the labels (create labels). Size for points: 0px.
   Other placement for the labels: Move all points or move some points (...before 0px.....)

Now you have two layers: Polygon layer and point layer with hidden labels at zoom xy.

2. Or do not show the labels. Show Information only, if a user click to a polygon. So you have much possibilities for many infos (numbers, text, links, pictures, videos (per `iframe`)).
   You could categorisized:
   100-200m²
   201-400m² etc.
   with different colors.
   Now the user click only into polygons for "him" m² size interest.

I think number "2" is a good solution, because it is an interactive map. The user must click to get information, but he also see different colors of polygons with a size sorting.
There are too much numbers within a small area.